# Is being transient a property of systems only in which there is a flow?

Tags: thermodynamics

Can the words "transient" or "steady" be used to describe systems which don't have a constant flow of mass, but operating only with the mass inside? I am assuming the system has no openings and closed.

Comment: Have you ever heard of transient heat conduction?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a metal rod at temperature $T_0$, and, at time zero, you suddenly change the temperature of one end of the rod to $T_1$, while the remaining surfaces of the rod is insulated.  Will the temperatures within the bar be changing with time?  If so, then this is a transient process,  even with no mass entering or exiting.